# About while(n) having no logical operator in c++

Tags: c++, loops, syntax

What does `while(n)` (`n` is an initialized integer) actually do in c++?

From the documentation:

> The while-loop simply repeats statement while expression is true.

But there's no logical operator in `while(n)` so suppose the loops run in a way that get n to zero, does that make it false? so does that means that writing `while(n)` is equivalent to `while(n!=0)`?

Comment: Any positive number is true.

Comment: Yes, `while (n)` continues until `n` evaluates to false, and `0` is the only integer that is implicitly convertible to false.

Comment: @HamZa: Any negative number is true too.

Comment: @Cameron cool, thanks. You can make that an answer BTW.

Comment: @Cameron, and especially -1 is true))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer:

Since `n` is an expression, it is evaluated in the context of the condition, which expects a boolean value. According to the [implicit conversion rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Boolean_conversions), any integer that is not 0 evaluates to true.

So yes, you can write `while (n)` instead of `while (n != 0)`. Note that if `n` was a user defined type with an overloaded `!=`, `void*`, or `bool` operator the two forms (if supported by the UDT) would not *necessarily* be equivalent (however any sane programmer would strive to make them equivalent in such a case).

Comment: What do you mean by "overloaded"?

Comment: @kuhaku: Well, you can define custom operators for user defined types. For example, you might define an `operator!=` that works on two pointers to your UDT and does a semantic comparison instead of the default pointer value comparison.

Answer (score 6):

Any non-zero value is considered "true" in C/C++.  C does not have a built-in `bool` type like C++ does, so this behavior was necessary for conditional statements to function, and was retained for likely a multitude of reasons beyond just backwards compatibility.  I happen to like it because it can reduce the amount of code needed for long conditionals, so I could write `if (i && j && k)` rather than `if (i != 0 && j != 0 && k != 0)`

Comment: C since C99 has `_Bool` and `<stdbool.h>`, to make things look more like C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator I knew about those, but I just looked it up and never realized _Bool was actually a type rather than a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Any number other then **0** is **TRUE**, only **0** stands for **FALSE**

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ define the semantics of the `while` statement (as well as `if` and others) slightly differently, but with just about the same effect.

In C (which I note isn't the language you asked about), the expression in a `while` can be of any scalar type. It's treated as true if and only if it compares unequal to `0`. That has the obvious meaning for integer types (including `_Bool`). For floating-point types, it's effectively compared against `0.0` (or `0.0F`, or `0.0L`). For pointer types it's compared to a null pointer.

In C++, the condition is *converted* to type `bool`. Conversion to `bool` for scalar types yields `false` if the expression is equal to `0`, `true` if it's unequal to `0`. So the effect is the same; it just gets there via a different logical path.

So in either C or C++, this:

```
while (n)
```

is equivalent to:

```
while (n != 0)
```

(Well, mostly. C++ operator overloading can mess things up if you do it badly.)

I personally prefer to write `!= 0` explicitly when the expression is not inherently Boolean, i.e., when different non-zero values can have different meanings. But that's a matter of taste, and plenty of programmers like the terseness of omitting the explicit test -- and you'll need to be able to read and understand code written in either style.